Build system is not showing in sublime text
I am installing SDL2 and am following this tutorial. When making the sublime-project file, the build system doesn't show in the tools menu.
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path":"bin/..",
            "file_exclude_patterns":["*.sublime-project"]   
        }
    ],
    
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name":"Build Debug",
            "working_dir":"${project_path}",
            "cmd":"g++ -c src/*.cpp -std=c++20 -g Wall -m64 -I include -I C:/SDL2-w64/include && g++ *.o -o bin/debug/main -L C:/SDL2-w64/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2-image && start bin/debug/main",
            "selector":"source.c++",
            "shell":true
        }
    ]
}

Any help why it not showing is appreciated.

It seems to work fine here; can you include a screenshot of what your Tools > Build System menu looks like? Project builds show up at the top of the menu in a separate section that is only visible in windows where the project is actually loaded.
